# XCode: "Analyzer skipped this file due to parse errors"

Tags: xcode, static-analysis

my project includes a simple C file with a header. Like this:

```
#ifndef __IMAGE_ARRAY_3D
#define __IMAGE_ARRAY_3D

typedef struct ImageArray3D {
    double *data;                       // The image data
    LargeElement *largestElements;      // c * nLargestElements
    int c, w, h, nLargestElements;
} tImageArray3D;     // Error points to here

...

#endif
```

When I run XCode's static analyzer, I get the following error:

> Analyzer skipped this file due to parse errors
>
> redefinition of 'ImageArray3D' as different kind of symbol

What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a solution for the problem: [Solution!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677879/strange-issue-after-upgrading-to-ios-4-1-sdk/3679692#3679692)

> The recommended solution is to add the
>   following to Other C Flags in your
>   project's build settings:
>   -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=040100 where you replace 040100 with your
>   deployment target version (030000 for
>   3.0, for example).

Comment: Better yet, set your project iOS deployment target appropriately: 
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 3.2

Comment: Specifically, your project's "iOS deployment target" build setting.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your project, or the OS X libraries, already define and use ImageArray3D.   Just rename it and it will probably work.

Comment: Thank you, but my project didn't define it.

Answer (score -9):

I found the cause of it:
If you select XCode's *Show issues only*, then you won't see the analyzer's errors in a file! Only if you select *Show all* option, you will see that the analyzer has had problems checking your project.

Comment: The solution is not to sweep the warning(s) under the carpet.

Comment: I didn't sweep them under the carpet. XCode was configured not to show them until I changed it.