# Strange issue after upgrading to iOS 4.1 SDK

Tags: iphone, ios

I've upgraded the iOS SDK to the newly released 4.1 and now I have the following error while building my app:

```
/DeveloperBeta/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGPDFContext.h:60:23     

/DeveloperBeta/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGPDFContext.h:60:23: error: expected function body after function declarator
```

Looking at that line in the .h file I see the following:

```
CG_EXTERN void CGPDFContextAddDocumentMetadata(CGContextRef context, CFDataRef metadata) CG_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_4_0);
```

The really interesting thing is the define __MAC_10_7 which appears not to be defined anywhere. I get this error when pre-compiling the .pch file of my app.

What's curious is that a simple hello world app compiles.

Any idea what can I do?

Thanks in advance!

Stelian

Comment: Huh.  The API changes doc says "no changes" to Core Graphics.  The MAC_10_7 shouldn't make a difference.  I don't see anything on the Apple forums yet, so I'd log a bug with Apple and see what they say.

Comment: I am having a very similar problem. I get it after upgrading to iOS 4.1 sdk coming from 4.0.2 sdk.

Comment: I am having a very similar problem. I get it after upgrading to iOS 4.1 sdk coming from 4.0.2 sdk. I get 11 errors to a project that has been compiling fine. Errors happen in CG*.h files. Same type of errors, some variables are not defined, if I remember, IPHONE_ something cannot be parsed. More details as soon as I get next to a mac computer. Interesting thing is that if i create a new project and copy files over, it builds, but running the app, some views are missing (inheriting UIVIEW and UITABLEVIEW)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is a known bug with the iOS 4.1 SDK and building using LLVM for the iPhone Simulator.  You can read all about it in [this thread](https://devforums.apple.com/message/287160#287160) on Apple's Developer Forums.

The recommended solution is to add the following to `Other C Flags` in your project's build settings: `-D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=040100` where you replace 040100 with your deployment target version (030000 for 3.0, for example).

Comment: Got errors when using eg 030100 (for 3.1), changed to 30100 which works fine!

Comment: Better yet, set your project's "iOS deployment target" build setting appropriately: IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 4.1

Answer (score 3):

I have this problem when using the LLVM compiler. Try recompiling using GCC and the problem (for me) goes away.

I'll keep investigating to determine if it is a general toolchain issue or if it's specific to my configuration.

--update:

So it looks like an issue with CLANG. LLVM GCC 4.2 works fine.

I still think it is likely a problem with my configuration. Even an empty project will not compile under LLVM CLANG 1.5 for me.

--update 2:

So it seems that the minimum required version setting is not being honoured in the project info settings. I've manually set it via:

Other C Flags: -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=031300

(for minimum of iOS 3.1, obviously - if you require a later version then you can use 040100 for version 4.0)

It does seem only to be a simulator problem with CLANG/LLVM. Compiling for the device directly seems to work just fine.

Comment: Even with the min required flag set in 'Other C Flags', I can't get this to work for the simulator. :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should be building with the latest Xcode 4, is this a requirement? The MAC_10_7 would be defined in the system headers shipped with the compiler I'm guessing could be in the SDK but I think not. I'm guessing this is when you build for the simulator.