# Xcode 3.2.4 Analyzer skipped this file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, clang-static-analyzer

Having just upgraded to iOS 4.1 (Xcode 3.2.4) I am getting warnings when using the static analyser that I don't think I was previously getting when using 3.2.3

[image]

Now the project compiles just fine, is this something that has changed or do I have something set wrong?

*NB: I have the build results window set to "All Messages"*

## EDIT:

I think it might be related to this:

[strange-issue-after-upgrading-to-ios-4-1-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677879/strange-issue-after-upgrading-to-ios-4-1-sdk)

much appreciated

Gary

Comment: Try adding: -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=040100 to build settings "Other C Flags" 040100 refers to 4.1, 3.2 would be 030200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set "Other C Flags" = `-D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=040100`