# XCode Static Analyzer: Analyzer skipped this file due to parse errors

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, static-analysis

I have been able to run the Static Analyzer on my code fine for months. All of a sudden now I am getting the error:

```
<command line>:0:0 Analyzer skipped this file due to parse errors
```

Not sure how to diagnose.

The first tile it skips is:

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGPDFContext.h:0:0 Analyzer skipped this file due to parse errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get these errors too if I try to use it when the target is set to the simulator, but if I switch the target to the device then it works.

Comment: As I explain in my answer, this is most likely due to this bug in the iOS 4.1 SDK: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677879/strange-issue-after-upgrading-to-ios-4-1-sdk

Answer (score 3):

Typically, this is a result of a syntax error or something else that is preventing your code from compiling.

Because you are only seeing errors when you go to analyze your code, not when it compiles, I bet that you are using the GCC compiler for your main application builds.  Clang / LLVM [has a bug in the iOS 4.1 SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677879/strange-issue-after-upgrading-to-ios-4-1-sdk) that causes compilation errors when targeting the Simulator, but not the device.  The Clang Static Analyzer is probably exhibiting this same bug.

The solution I provide in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677879/strange-issue-after-upgrading-to-ios-4-1-sdk/3679692#3679692) to the above-linked question should work to fix this as well.  However, it may lead to compilation errors when you switch back to build your application with GCC, so I recommend switching your compiler over to LLVM.  Unless you are using C++ code, I recommend using LLVM for iPhone projects anyway, due to the minor performance boosts you can get in your compiled application with it.